# Angular-cli integration with Sailsjs

Tags: angular, sails.js, angular-cli

How to serve the dist folder generated from ng-build with sails to be the front-end of your application along with the backend api generated by sails ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well i managed to get this work, just put this for anyone else wondering

In config/routes.js edit:

```
module.exports.routes = {
  '/': {
    view: 'index.html'
  }
};
```

then copy your dist folder content from angular `ng build --prod` to the sails assets folder, then sails lift

Comment: @noyruto88 what error do you get or how does it not working ?